# Horizontal Alignment of UI controls in android

Tags: android, android-layout

Please provide a solution to arrange two EditView controls same horizontal position.  How to left align EditView of Port with EditView of IP Address.  Also providing screen shot of current view

[image]

please find current layout code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="210dip"
android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
android:background="#DDDDDD"
>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/head"
    android:text="Connection Settings"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textColor="#0000ff"
    android:textSize="10pt" 
/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_ip"
    android:layout_width="125dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="10pt"
    android:textColor="#444444"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="9dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:layout_below="@id/head"
    android:text="IP Address"/>
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_ip"
    android:layout_width="150dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tv_ip"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/tv_ip"/>
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_port"
    android:layout_width="125dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="10pt"
    android:textColor="#444444"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/tv_ip"
    android:layout_marginRight="9dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:text="Port"/>
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_port"
    android:layout_width="150dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tv_port"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/tv_port"
    android:layout_below="@id/et_ip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="17dip"
    />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_Save"
    android:layout_width="100dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/et_port"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="110dip"
    android:text="Save" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to add `android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/et_ip"` in the code of your `EditText` **et_port**.
Here is the corrected code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="210dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:background="#DDDDDD" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/head"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Connection Settings"
        android:textColor="#0000ff"
        android:textSize="10pt" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_ip"
        android:layout_width="125dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/head"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="9dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
        android:text="IP Address"
        android:textColor="#444444"
        android:textSize="10pt" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_ip"
        android:layout_width="150dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/tv_ip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tv_ip"
        android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_port"
        android:layout_width="125dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/tv_ip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="9dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
        android:text="Port"
        android:textColor="#444444"
        android:textSize="10pt" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_port"
        android:layout_width="150dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/tv_port"
        android:layout_below="@id/et_ip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tv_port"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/et_ip"
        android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_Save"
        android:layout_width="100dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/et_port"
        android:layout_marginLeft="110dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
        android:text="Save" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't have much time to re-work your current layout, but you should use a `GridLayout` for something like this, when you need to align forms and entry fields - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html

If you want a tutorial, give this quick one a shot - http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/669 it shows clearly how you would align these up.

Notice how you can have spaces:

[image: GridLayout example from Blog Tutorial]

Hopefully that helps get you going in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="210dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:background="#DDDDDD" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/head"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Connection Settings"
        android:textColor="#0000ff"
        android:textSize="10pt" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_ip"
        android:layout_width="125dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/head"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="9dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
        android:text="IP Address"
        android:textColor="#444444"
        android:textSize="10pt" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_ip"
        android:layout_width="150dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/tv_ip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tv_ip"
        android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_port"
        android:layout_width="125dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/tv_ip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="9dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
        android:text="Port"
        android:textColor="#444444"
        android:textSize="10pt" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_port"
        android:layout_width="150dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tv_port"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_port"
        android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_Save"
        android:layout_width="100dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/et_port"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Save" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code `

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/head"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="Connection Settings"
    android:textColor="#0000ff"
    android:textSize="10pt" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_ip"
        android:layout_width="160dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="IP Address"
        android:textColor="#444444"
        android:textSize="10pt" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_ip"
        android:layout_width="150dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tv_ip"
        android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_port"
        android:layout_width="160dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_ip"
        android:text="Port"
        android:textColor="#444444"
        android:textSize="10pt" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_port"
        android:layout_width="150dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tv_port"
        android:layout_below="@+id/et_ip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_port"
        android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background" />
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_Save"
    android:layout_width="100dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="Save" />
```

` and let me know if any issues are present